# Where can I buy KamiNomi Manga?

Tags: resources, the-world-god-only-knows

I want to buy the manga/magazine of full volume of KamiNomi, but don't know where to find it.

I live in the the Philippines. Anyone knows where I can buy one?

Comment: there's this online shop called Eiwa Manga Store.. try looking it up

Comment: They sell english version?

Comment: yes, they also do shippings for translated versions.. you can read more about it from their website

Comment: @Ezui - Ok, I'll check it out! Thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

The manga series has not been licensed in English unfortunately.

You can stream the anime via [CrunchyRoll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/the-world-god-only-knows) or buy the DVD/BluRay through [RightStuf](http://www.rightstuf.com/rssite/facetedSearch/?search=The%20World%20God%20Only%20Knows#/?s=The%20World%20God%20Only%20Knows) (although you may need to enquire about shipping estimates/availabilty)

Comment: That's... A shame......T_T I want to read the manga not via online.. I want to collect it.. If you know what I mean...

Comment: @JackFrost I know :( there's something about physical manga that's very nice

Comment: Yeah... The feeling of having it in your hands its thrilling... Hope they publish an english version of it...